# How to using Spring @RequestMapping annotation with attribute name in Spring MVC

Tags: java, django, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

As I know in the Django Framework offers a way to name URLs so it's easy to reference them in view methods and templates.

For example:

```py
# Definition in coffeehouse/urls.py
path('',TemplateView.as_view(template_name='homepage.html'),name="homepage")

# Definition in view method
from django.http import HttpResponsePermanentRedirect
from django.urls import reverse

def method(request):
    ....
    return HttpResponsePermanentRedirect(reverse('homepage'))

# Definition in template
<a href="{% url 'homepage' %}">Back to home page</a>
```

what is the name attribute in Spring @RequestMapping annotation?

Is it the same with the name URL in the Django Framework?

how to using @RequestMapping annotation with attribute name in Spring MVC?

Comment: See [Building URIs to controllers](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/thymeleafspring.html#building-uris-to-controllers), which references [Building URIs to Controllers and methods from views](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/4.1.2.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-links-to-controllers-from-views)

Comment: First link in previous comment is for Thymeleaf, second link is for JSP.

Comment: in the Django Framework, I can redirect to URL in views (like controller in Spring) by using the reverse() function. For example: [Reverse resolution of URLs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/http/urls/#examples)
Can Sping do that?. Thank you @Andreas

Comment: To build a redirect URL from a Spring handler, use [`MvcUriComponentsBuilder`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/method/annotation/MvcUriComponentsBuilder.html), e.g. the [`fromMappingName(String mappingName)`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/method/annotation/MvcUriComponentsBuilder.html#fromMappingName-java.lang.String-) method is what is used by the links in my previous comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To build a URL from the mapping annotation of a handler method, use:

- **From JSP:** See [Building URIs to Controllers and methods from views](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/4.1.2.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-links-to-controllers-from-views)

  > As of 4.1 every `@RequestMapping` is assigned a default name based on the capital letters of the class and the full method name. For example, the method `getFoo` in class `FooController` is assigned the name "FC#getFoo".
  >
  > [...]
  >
  > The Spring JSP tag library provides a function called `mvcUrl` that can be used to prepare links to controller methods based on this mechanism.
  >
  > For example given:
  >
  > ```java
  > @RequestMapping("/people/{id}/addresses")
  > public class MyController {
  >
  >     @RequestMapping("/{country}")
  >     public HttpEntity getAddress(@PathVariable String country) { ... }
  > }
  > ```
  >
  > The following JSP code can prepare a link:
  >
  > ```html
  > <%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" prefix="s" %>
  > ...
  > <a href="${s:mvcUrl('PC#getPerson').arg(0,'US').buildAndExpand('123')}">Get Person</a>
  > ```
- **From Thymeleaf:** See [Building URIs to controllers](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/thymeleafspring.html#building-uris-to-controllers).

  > Since version 4.1, Spring allows the possibility to build links to annotated controllers directly from views, without the need to know the URIs these controllers are mapped to.
  >
  > In Thymeleaf, this can be achieved by means of the `#mvc.url(...)` expression object method, which allows the specification of controller methods by the capital letters of the controller class they are in, followed by the name of the method itself. This is equivalent to JSP’s `spring:mvcUrl(...)` custom function.
  >
  > For example, for:
  >
  > ```java
  > public class ExampleController {
  >
  >     @RequestMapping("/data")
  >     public String getData(Model model) { ... return "template" }
  >
  >     @RequestMapping("/data")
  >     public String getDataParam(@RequestParam String type) { ... return "template" }
  >
  > }
  > ```
  >
  > The following code will create a link to it:
  >
  > ```html
  > <a th:href="${(#mvc.url('EC#getData')).build()}">Get Data Param</a>
  > <a th:href="${(#mvc.url('EC#getDataParam').arg(0,'internal')).build()}">Get Data Param</a>
  > ```
- **Redirect from another handler:** See [`MvcUriComponentsBuilder.fromMappingName(String mappingName)`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/method/annotation/MvcUriComponentsBuilder.html#fromMappingName-java.lang.String-).

  > Create a URL from the name of a Spring MVC controller method's request mapping.
  >
  > The configured `HandlerMethodMappingNamingStrategy` determines the names of controller method request mappings at startup. By default all mappings are assigned a name based on the capital letters of the class name, followed by "#" as separator, and then the method name. For example "PC#getPerson" for a class named PersonController with method getPerson. In case the naming convention does not produce unique results, an explicit name may be assigned through the name attribute of the `@RequestMapping` annotation.
  >
  > This is aimed primarily for use in view rendering technologies and EL expressions. The Spring URL tag library registers this method as a function called "mvcUrl".
  >
  > For example, given this controller:
  >
  > ```java
  > @RequestMapping("/people")
  > class PersonController {
  >
  >     @RequestMapping("/{id}")
  >     public HttpEntity<Void> getPerson(@PathVariable String id) { ... }
  >
  > }
  > ```
  >
  > A JSP can prepare a URL to the controller method as follows:
  >
  > ```html
  > <%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" prefix="s" %>
  >
  > <a href="${s:mvcUrl('PC#getPerson').arg(0,"123").build()}">Get Person</a>
  > ```
  >
  > Note that it's not necessary to specify all arguments. Only the ones required to prepare the URL, mainly `@RequestParam` and `@PathVariable`).

  To use it, you would do something like this:

  ```
  return "redirect:" + MvcUriComponentsBuilder.fromMappingName("PC#getPerson")
                                              .arg(0,"123")
                                              .build();
  ```